SVG Progress bar flickering and not showing the running progress
I am running one SVG Progress bar, Which code was present in Javascript and HTML and i converted this to the React js with tailwind css. After converting the code i found here is like after set the value and click the button number is increasing for the progress but progress bar is flickering and not showing the progress bars.
I tried so far: 
Below is my complete code.

import React, {useRef, useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [maxSpeed, setMaxSpeed] = useState(0);
  const [tgtSpeed, setTgtSpeed] = useState(0);
  const [q1Num, setQ1Num] = useState(0);
  const [q2Num, setQ2Num] = useState(0);
  const [q3Num, setQ3Num] = useState(0);
  const [q4Num, setQ4Num] = useState(0);
  const[ctgtSpeed, setCTgtSpeed] = useState(0);
  const[qty, Setqty] = useState('');
  const circleRef = useRef<any>(null);
  const tickerRef = useRef<any>(null);
  const drpDownRef = useRef<any>(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    tickerRef.current.setAttribute('transform', `rotate(${270 / 100 * 0})`);
    circleRef.current.setAttribute('stroke-dashoffset', 100 - 0);
  },[]);
 
const splitNumber = (num = 1, parts = 1) => {
  let n = Math.floor(num / parts);
  const arr = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < parts; i++){
      arr.push(n)
  };
  return arr;
};
  const MaxSpeedValue = (mxText:any) =>{
    var splitData = splitNumber(parseInt(mxText), 4);
     setQ1Num (splitData[0]);
     setQ2Num(splitData[1] + splitData[2]);
     setQ3Num(splitData[1] + splitData[2] + splitData[3]);;
     setQ4Num(mxText);
     setMaxSpeed(mxText);
   }
   const TargetSpeeValue=(event: any)=>{
    setTgtSpeed(event.target.value);
   }
   const selectOption =(event: any)=> {
           let dropdown = event.currentTarget;
           // get the index of the selected option
           let selectedIndex = dropdown.selectedIndex;
           // get a selected option and text value using the text property
           let selectedValue = dropdown.options[selectedIndex].text;
           Setqty(selectedValue);
        }
   const StartProgress =()=>{
        StartProgressSpeed();
   }
   const StartProgressSpeed = ()=>{
    let degree = 0;
    let percentage = 0;
    if(maxSpeed > 100)
      {
        moreThanHundred = true;
      }
    let progressbar = document.querySelectorAll('.progress-bar');
      progressbar.forEach(function (circle) {
        const speedDiff = maxSpeed - tgtSpeed;
        const circumference = 133;
        var interval = setInterval(function () {
          if (degree >= tgtSpeed) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            return;
          }
           if(moreThanHundred){
            percentage = degree / maxSpeed;
            const progressCalc = (circumference * percentage);
            circleRef.current.setAttribute('stroke-dashoffset', 100 - progressCalc);
            tickerRef.current.setAttribute('transform', `rotate(${270 / 100 * progressCalc})`);
          }
          else
          {
            percentage = degree / maxSpeed;
            const progressCalc = (circumference * percentage);
            circleRef.current.setAttribute('stroke-dashoffset', 100 - degree);
            tickerRef.current.setAttribute('transform', `rotate(${270 / 100 * degree})`);
          }
          setCTgtSpeed(degree);
          setMaxSpeed(maxSpeed);
        }, 50);
      });
    }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="w-full h-full flex items-center justify-center">
   <div className='mr-20'>
  <input type="text" id="txtMaxSpeed" placeholder="Enter max speed" onChange={(e)=> MaxSpeedValue(e.target.value)} className="w-[142px]"/><br/><br/>
  <input type="text" id="txtTargetSpeed" placeholder="Set target speed" className="w-[142px]" onChange={(e)=> TargetSpeeValue(e)}/><br/><br/>
  <select id = "dropdown" ref={drpDownRef} onChange={(e)=> selectOption(e)} className="w-[100px]">
      <option>-- Select --</option>
      <option>C/h</option>
      <option>ml</option>
      <option>liter</option>
   </select>
   <br/><br/>
  <button id="btnStart" className="bg-[skyblue] h-[43px] w-[100px] font-[bold] text-lg" onClick={()=> StartProgress()}>Start</button>
  </div>
      <svg className="progress-bar" width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 100 110" fill="none">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="lg1" x1="0.7" gradientTransform="rotate(45)">
      <stop offset="0%" stopColor="#eee" />
      <stop offset="100%" stopColor="#ddd" />
    </linearGradient>
    <mask id="m1">
      <circle transform="rotate(135)" stroke="white"
        strokeWidth="12" r="44" strokeDasharray="270 360"
        pathLength="360"/>
    </mask>
    <radialGradient id="rg1">
      <stop offset="0%" stopColor="#aaa" />
      <stop offset="40%" stopColor="#ccc" />
      <stop offset="90%" stopColor="white" />
    </radialGradient>
  </defs>
  <ellipse cx="50" cy="102" rx="40" ry="8" fill="url(#rg1)" />
  <g transform="translate(50 50)">
    <circle stroke="#eee" strokeWidth="12" r="44"/>
    <g mask="url(#m1)">
      <rect transform="translate(-50 -50)" width="100" height="100"
        fill="url(#lg1)" />
      <circle stroke="#ccc" strokeWidth="12" r="44"
        strokeDasharray=".5 4.5" pathLength="360"/>
      <circle stroke="#bbb" strokeWidth="6" r="41"/>
    </g>
    <g transform="rotate(135)">
      <circle id="c1" ref={circleRef} stroke="#0b60e9" strokeWidth="8" r="42"
        strokeDasharray="100 133" pathLength="133.5"/>
    </g>
    <line transform="rotate(45) translate(38 0)" stroke="#aaa"
      strokeWidth="1" x2="12" />
    <line transform="rotate(135) translate(38 0)" stroke="#aaa"
      strokeWidth="1" x2="12" />
    <g id="g1" ref={tickerRef} transform="rotate(216)">
      <line transform="rotate(-225) translate(38 0)" stroke="#000"
        strokeWidth=".5" x2="12" />
      <polygon transform="rotate(-225) translate(36 0)"
        points="0,-4.5 0,4.5 5,0" fill="#000"/>
    </g>
    <text id="t3" x="10px" y="-13px" fontFamily="sans-serif" fontSize="9" fontWeight="200"
      textAnchor="right" dominantBaseline="right" fill="#0b60e9">{qty}</text>
    <text id="t1" fontFamily="sans-serif" fontSize="20" fontWeight="400"
      textAnchor="middle" dominantBaseline="middle" fill="#0b60e9">{ctgtSpeed}</text>
    <text id="t2" y="10" fontFamily="sans-serif" fontSize="9"
      fontWeight="400" textAnchor="start" dominantBaseline="hanging" fill="#000">{maxSpeed}</text>
  </g>
</svg>
<label id="lblQ1" className='absolute text-xl text-[#c8c8cc] font-bold left-[725px] top-[243px]'>{q1Num}</label>
<label id="lblQ2" className='absolute text-xl text-[#c8c8cc] font-bold left-[708px] top-[53px]'>{q2Num}</label>
<label id="lblQ3" className='absolute text-xl text-[#c8c8cc] font-bold left-[1015px] top-11'>{q3Num}</label>
<label id="lblMaxSpeed" className='absolute text-xl text-[#c8c8cc] font-bold left-[1015px] top-60'>{q4Num}</label>
</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;


Expectation: So the logic here is like, After running application user can get three fields and one scale circle progress bar empty.
max value, target value and select size.
When user feed value in max field based on the value will get equal divide in four parts and will show near of the progress bar.
Expectation: Here max value will be the final value. But progress bar will run till target value only and the ticker which is a part of progress could also run till target value only.
Here user can feed more than 100 value. Could be any even number > 100, Same for target number as well.
Need help on this.

i think you need to run your useEffect after updating the fields, each time, so you need to make it target a state change

@BurhamB.Soliman: I updated my code now the useEffect run only once on load and the progress bar is woking fine. Now i need the expectation asked in question.

you could make a state that change upon fields change so you can get new updates to the bar on change

I have updated my code little more to check if user provide max value to 100 and target value to 80 then progress bar is working as expected. But if he is going more than 100 e.g; 1000 and target : 800. In that case it is not working.

I find the 1 percent value of maxspeed and divided with degree value and set it to the circle and it is working as expected.

I have got a fix for the above asked. Now calculated value like below:


 const speedRatio = props.maxValue / 100;
          const targetPercentage = degree / speedRatio;
          circleRef.current?.setAttribute(
            "stroke-dashoffset",
            `${100 - targetPercentage}`,
          );



And it is working as expected.
Thank you all for your suggestion.
